# how to add vesting in customspec.json?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, vesting

i am using Substrate i want to add Vesting in my customspec whats the format for adding it?

`i tried using this but it did't work`

[image]

```
genesis_config of pallet_vesting
```

[image]

i am getting this error

> Error: Service(Other("Error parsing spec file: invalid type: string
> "5FvteDB7Um775LKdhUiB6e64NZZoxFnCi1EE2Gx5y1XGwuMe", expected a tuple
> of size 4 at line 187 column 60"))

Comment: Looks like you need to pass in a Vec with a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the format for adding vesting in customspec.json

[image]